# Cannot execute SQL query

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the following code to execute a SQL query in vb.net :

```vb
  opdragaliaens.CommandText = "UPDATE UBH " &
                              "SET ton = wh.total_net " &
                              "FROM UniekeBlokkeHistories UBH " &
                              "INNER JOIN ( " &
                              " SELECT grower, block, section, oesjaar, SUM(net) AS total_net " &
                              "   FROM wbridge_history " &
                              "   GROUP BY grower, block, section, oesjaar " &
                              ") AS wh ON " &
                              "  wh.grower = UBH.Lid_No " &
                              "  AND wh.[block] = UBH.Plaas_no " &
                              "  AND wh.section = UBH.Blok_no " &
                              "  AND wh.oesjaar = UBH.oesjaar " &
                              "Update()  t1 " &
                              "set " &
                              "t1.alias = t2.alias, " &
                              "t1.Plaasnaam = t2.blkname, " &
                              "t1.Kultivar = t2.variety, " &
                              "t1.Klas = t2.yearclass " &
                              "   FROM " &
                              "   UniekeBlokkeHistories t1 " &
                              "Inner Join wbridge_history t2 " &
                              "On t1.Lid_No = t2.grower " &
                              "And t1.Plaas_no = t2.[block] " &
                              "And t1.Blok_no = t2.section " &
                              "And t1.Oesjaar = t2.oesjaar"

Try
     opdragaliaens.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
     MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

When I run the query I get a message :

> Incorrect syntax near '('

I cannot see on which line the error occurs.

The query works in SQL Server Management Studio.

What am I missing in VB.net?

Regards

Comment: Writing SQL with all that concatenation makes it harder to read.  I would suggest that you use a single multi-line string literal if you're using a recent version of VB that supports it and an XML literal otherwise.  Both options avoid all the quotes and ampersands, thus making the text less noisy, easier to read and less error-prone.

Comment: `"Update()"` in `()` may meaning less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have open and close parentheses `"Update()  t1 " &` in between your update scripts. I suggest to have a separate call on your 2nd udpate.

```vb
opdragaliaens.CommandText = "UPDATE UBH " &
    "SET ton = wh.total_net " &
    "FROM UniekeBlokkeHistories UBH " &
    "INNER JOIN ( " &
    " SELECT grower, block, section, oesjaar, SUM(net) AS total_net " &
    "   FROM wbridge_history " &
    "   GROUP BY grower, block, section, oesjaar " &
    ") AS wh ON " &
    "  wh.grower = UBH.Lid_No " &
    "  And wh.[block] = UBH.Plaas_no " &
    "  and wh.section = UBH.Blok_no " &
    "  and wh.oesjaar = UBH.oesjaar; " &
    "Update t1 " &
    "set " &
    "t1.alias = t2.alias, " &
    "t1.Plaasnaam = t2.blkname, " &
    "t1.Kultivar = t2.variety, " &
    "t1.Klas = t2.yearclass " &
    "   FROM " &
    "   UniekeBlokkeHistories t1 " &
    "Inner Join wbridge_history t2 " &
    "On t1.Lid_No = t2.grower " &
    "And t1.Plaas_no = t2.[block] " &
    "And t1.Blok_no = t2.section " &
    "And t1.Oesjaar = t2.oesjaar"

Try
opdragaliaens.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```